# Read Single Value from CSV (LINQtoCSV)

Tags: c#, csv, readfile, linqtocsv

I want to read a single Value from a CSV File (e.g. Line 3, Column 2).

I'm using the LINQtoCSV NuGet Paket (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library#_articleTop)

```
class Product
{
    [CsvColumn(Name = "Steckplatz", FieldIndex = 1)]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [CsvColumn(CharLength = 5, FieldIndex = 2)]
    public short Steckzyklen { get; set; }
    [CsvColumn(OutputFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", FieldIndex = 3)]
    public DateTime Austauschdatum { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CsvFileDescription inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
    {
        SeparatorChar = ',',
        FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
    };
    CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();
    IEnumerable<Product> products =
        cc.Read<Product>("Insert Steckzyklen Zähler.csv", inputFileDescription);

    var productsByName =
        from p in products
        orderby p.Name
        select new { p.Name, p.Steckzyklen, p.Austauschdatum };

    Console.WriteLine(products);
}
```

The variable "products" is an IEnumerable. The whole CSV File gets saved in products.

This is my CSV File:

```
Steckplatz,Steckzyklen,Austauschdatum
KnaufUpdateBox1Steckplatz1,159,2022-02-25 14:30:32
KnaufUpdateBox1Steckplatz2,256,2022-02-25 14:30:32
KnaufUpdateBox1Steckplatz3,15896,2022-02-25 14:30:32
KnaufUpdateBox1Steckplatz4,489,2022-02-25 14:30:32
KnaufUpdateBox1Steckplatz5,6875,2022-02-25 14:30:32
KnaufUpdateBox1Steckplatz6,2856,2022-02-25 14:30:32
KnaufUpdateBox1Steckplatz7,874,2022-02-25 14:30:32
KnaufUpdateBox1Steckplatz8,3874,2022-02-25 14:30:32
KnaufUpdateBox2Steckplatz1,3689,2022-02-25 14:30:32
KnaufUpdateBox2Steckplatz2,3689,2022-02-25 14:30:32
KnaufUpdateBox2Steckplatz3,983,2022-02-25 14:30:32
KnaufUpdateBox2Steckplatz4,287,2022-02-25 14:30:32
KnaufUpdateBox2Steckplatz5,398,2022-02-25 14:30:32
KnaufUpdateBox2Steckplatz6,28567,2022-02-25 14:30:32
KnaufUpdateBox2Steckplatz7,389,2022-02-25 14:30:32
KnaufUpdateBox2Steckplatz8,938,2022-02-25 14:30:32
```

with LINQPad i could view what was stored in products.
I have not managed to get only a specific value from products. Could someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know exactly which row and column you're looking for, why are you using LinqToCsv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (e.g. Line 3, Column 2).

Assuming products is presented in the order of the file

```
products.Skip(2).First().Steckzyklen;
```

- `Skip` skips past the initial two items in the enumeration,
- `First` grabs the third item, and
- `Steckzyklen` gets the second column

The notion of "column 2" is somewhat lost in favor of named properties, such being the whole raison d'etre for LINQtoCSV; you could recover it by programmatically inspecting the attributes for which one has FieldIndex 2, but I figure that this is a nonsense when FieldIndex=2 is hard coded, and Steckzyklen is hard coded; they're thus synonymous